# Test case scripts for PHP, Javascript & Ruby

Tags: php, javascript, ruby

I am writing several script test cases to test memory and cpu time for PHP/Javascript/Ruby under different scenarios for OOP and general scripting scenarios.

So far I have done:
1) 1 million iterations, each time running same function and adding items to the Stack,
2) The Fibanacci sequence to the interpreters maximum (using mostly floats),

I am struggling to think of good test cases which would demonstrate which is the more powerful and where. I would very much appreciate any ideas on scenarios to run as I have written several more myself but I do not feel like they do much more than the first 2 already do.

Comment: these aren't test cases you're describing, they're benchmarks.

Comment: @SDC yes I guess it is more accurately described as benchmarking for the 3 languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/). You'll find lots of examples there.